# Ruby - Possible to pass a block as a param as an actual block to another function?

Tags: ruby, instance-eval

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
def call_block(in_class = "String", &block)
    instance = eval("#{in_class}.new")
    puts "instance class: #{instance.class}"
    instance.instance_eval{ block.call }
end


# --- TEST EXAMPLE ---
# This outputs "class: String" every time
"sdlkfj".instance_eval {  puts "class: #{self.class}" }

# This will only output "class: Object" every time
# I'm trying to get this to output "class: String" though
call_block("String") { puts "class: #{self.class}" }
```

On the line where it says "instance.instance_eval{ block.call }", I'm trying to find another way to make the new instance variable run instance eval on the block.  The only way I can think of to get it to do that is to pass instance_eval the original block, not as a variable or anything, but as a real block like in the test example.

Any tips?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. You can pass the block to the other method by prepending the block variable with an ampersand like so:

```
def foo &blk
  # now, blk is a variable bound to a block object
  bar &blk
end
```

The reason your are getting "class: Object" is that Ruby uses lexical scoping. This means that self in `puts "class: #{self.class}"` refers to `main`, the default context.

Comment: What??? It was that simple?  Hahaha, thanks!  I was stuck on this one for days! :)

Comment: the term to search for was 'block parameters'; easier in hindsight though :)